# Kernel Density: How do the terms 'global' and 'pilot' translate?

Tags: probability, density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, relative-risk

I nearly most of the articles on kernel smoothing or concepts that use kernel density estimations, authors speak of 'pilot'  and 'global'.

- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008925425102

"[...] Abramson (1982) suggests taking λi ∝ f (x i )−1/2 ; implementation thus requires use of a pilot estimate of f (x), usually taken to be a fixed kernel estimator.[...] We are concerned with the modelling of variable bandwidths λ j associated with each y j . Each λ j is considered to be a product of a pilot bandwidth λ and a local bandwidth factor δ j , such as that in the Silverman (1986) implementation of the Abramson (1982) estimator. The x i and pilot bandwidth λ are considered fixed, while each y j has conditional density [...]"

[image]

"[... ] The parameterisation of the prior is important. When choosing d1 and d2 we would like the expected value of δ j for the
resulting prior distribution to be 1 (since λ j = λδ j ), and again
this is similar in spirit to Silverman’s version of the Abramson
estimator. Section A.2 of the Appendix shows that this results
in the following relationship between the prior parameters:
[image]

In effect then, we have two user inputs with this method: the
global (pilot) bandwidth λ and the first parameter (d1 ) of the
Gamma prior on the δ j . The value chosen for λ will affect the resulting density estimate in the obvious way. The parameter d1
effectively controls the amount of variability among the δ j (and
hence the λ j ): larger values of d1 give less variability in terms
of λ j , and smaller values of d1 give more variability. As a result,
choosing too large a value for d1 may give an adaptive density estimate which is indistinguishable from the fixed estimate, while
choosing a very small d1 will produce a curve which exhibits
too much local variation. [...]"

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparr/sparr.pdf

Strg + f -> search for pilot or gobal

- https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.7577

The pre-eminent approach to sample-point adaptation is due to Abramson.35
Abramson suggested setting h(u; f)=h0f(u)−1/2, that is, bandwidths being inversely proportional to the square root of the target density itself. In practice, in line with Silverman,  Abramson's smoothing regimen is implemented as

[image]

where f̃ is a pilot estimate of the unknown density constructed via (1) with a fixed pilot bandwidth̃h; h0 is an overall smoothing parameter for the variable bandwidths referred to as the global bandwidth;

- https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/parasitology/article/identification-of-highrisk-regions-for-schistosomiasis-in-the-guichi-region-of-china-an-adaptive-kernel-density-estimationbased-approach/EDB2176CA652974E65CACFC6D1EED78F
- https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/epidemiology-and-infection/article/spatiotemporal-distribution-of-covid19-infection-in-england-between-january-and-june-2020/E7F666A7667864E38BA844B1AFF1070A

What does 'pilot'  and 'global' mean in the context of (adaptive) kernel density estimation?

Comment: Nearly all of the links are paywalled, could you give some quotes mentioning them?

Comment: @Tim I added some more information. Not sure if that helps though...